# How to print long primitive in Java

Tags: java, overflow, long-integer

Relatively new to Java and possibly some stupid question. Here is the code:

```
long a = 3232235521L;
long b = 192 * 16777216 + 168 * 65536 + 0 * 256 + 1;

System.out.println("a="+a);
System.out.println("b="+b);
```

The output:

```
a=3232235521
b=-1062731775
```

According to Java documentation max value for long 2^63-1 and that is: 9223372036854775807. So for b, there is no overflow, so why b isn't 3232235521?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 2 of your code, all your operands are integers, which is why the results of the operations will also be an integer.

Since the result(3,232,235,521) will not fit inside an integer(max value being 2^31 - 1), this results in an **integer overflow**, which is why you are getting the negative result.

So, you will need to use Long literals to get an accurate result. Change Line 2 to the below code.

```
long b = 192L * 16777216L + 168L * 65536L + 0L * 256L + 1L;
```

The above code should give you the correct output.

Comment: max value for `long is 2^63-1` then y it should not fit??

Comment: Since the right hand side of your expression only has integers, the results of the individual operations will be set as an integer. Whichever results do not fit in an ```int```, will overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are using integer primitives during the math and it's only converted at the end, after the integer overflow. You might want to use 192L * 16777216L + 168L * 65536L + 0L * 256L + 1L;

Answer (score 0):

You are only doing the conversion to long on the assignment - up until that point everything is an integer and that is why you are seeing an overflow halfway through your calculation.

The code should be:

`long b = 192l * 16777216l + 168l * 65536l + 0l * 256l + 1l;`